# how to edit the SharePoint 2007 main global breadcrumb link

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, global, breadcrumbs

I need to be able to edit the text and corresponding link of the primary global breadcrumb link in a SharePoint 2007 site.

This is the link at the top left of the page that is intended to point the user back to the root of the primary site.  This is not one of the tabs.

We believe this site was originally created as a subsite in some dev environment, then copied over as the primary site of a new installation.  The primary breadcrumb link still has the name of that sub-site and points to it as well, despite this site having a completely different url and name.

I don't see any out of the box way to manage this link, so I'm hoping someone knows of a way to do this.  Preferrably, without touching the content database directly.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Is this the breadcrumb above the site logo, uppermost top left of the browser? It *should* be fully dynamic as it's set by a control in the page's masterpage. Was a custom masterpage used in this site?

Comment: Yes, this is the breadcrumb above the site logo...uppermost top left.  We do use a custom master page.  What should I be looking for in the master page?

Comment: `<asp:SiteMapPath SiteMapProvider="SPSiteMapProvider" id="GlobalNavigationSiteMap"...` That's the start of the tag that should output that navigation.

Comment: Great, thanks. Solved the problem by hiding the global breadcrumbs.  #ctl00_PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation_PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap_GlobalNavigationSiteMap
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

Found the master page in: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\default.master on our TFS server.

Replaced line 42:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server">
```

with

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server"
```

visible="false">

Then the top most navigation bar is hidden.